# Easy way to auto bcc all outgoing mail to my gmail account from lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, rules

Currently I have rules that send incoming email to my gmail account but now I want to have my own sent mail copied to my gmail account.

My problem is that my lotus note account is space limited and because of that I need to delete my email periodically, but I'm asked for information in that same emails frequently.

As a side note I don't have any control in the configuration, for example I can't activate the imap server to use a better mail client.

Update: Lotus Notes version 8.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a Notes client installed on my current machine, but I was a Notes developer for many years. As an end user, there's no way to automatically bcc, but you can use simple agents to send new records in your Sent folder on a schedule (i.e. once a day.)

Here are pretty specific instructions from Notes Help that should work in Notes versions 5-7.x; if you're on 8, it's very different and I don't have any experience with that. Anything in italics are my notes that are specific to your situation.

To create an agent, you must first open the database and choose Create - Agent. Notes displays the Agent Properties box and opens the Programmer's pane.

**In the Agent Properties box:**

1. Click the Basics tab.
2. Enter a name for the agent in the Name field.
3. (Optional) Enter a comment in the Comment field. Comments appear in the agents list.
4. Select Shared if this agent will be used by other users. Select Private if you want the agent to be an agent that only you can run. *You want to choose Private.*
5. *SKIP THIS STEP - you don't need it for the kind of thing you want to do.*
   If the agent will search for text in documents, you can specify the following settings in the Options section:

   - Check "Store search in Search bar menu" to display your search query in the Search bar.
   - Check "Store highlights in document" so that your search matches are highlighted in the searched documents.
6. To run agents that do not appear in the user interface, select "Run in background client thread." *You want to do this.*
7. In the Runtime section of the properties box, choose one of the following triggers for the agent. Different options appear depending on the trigger you choose. *Select On Schedule*

   - Select "On event," then select the event which triggers the agent.
   - Select "On schedule," then schedule the time the agent triggers.
8. Click the Security tab of the Agent Properties box to set up security for the agent. *Skip this; just leave the default security settings in place.*
9. Close the Agent properties box after you have filled in the necessary fields.

**In the Programmer's pane:**

1. Click Add Action to open the Add Action dialog box and specify a simple action(s) for the agent to perform. (Choose actions in the order you want them to run.) - *choose Send Document*
2. If you want the agent to search for a document, select the Objects tab and then "Document Selection." Click the "Add Condition" button to display the Add Condition dialog box and set up search conditions. - *Choose In Folder, then select your Sent folder and hit OK; then click Add Condition again and choose By Date -> Date Created -> Is in the last 1 day.*
3. Choose File - Save to save the agent in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you found yourself repeatly doing these actions, especially in CRM email system, you might need a browser extension to help you out. I found a great one, using it for a while now. It's the best addon and it's free. The Chrome extension is available at: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hfjgikgjcgdhlklibkcobckkhklaeodd

Comment: It might be worth adding how exactly this would work - maybe give an example of a workflow with this